# Understanding nginx config file structure

Tags: ssl, nginx, webserver

I am fairly new to nginx. After I installed everything, I noticed that I am not quite sure, which conf file will be used. I have those config files:

- `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
- `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.default`
- `/etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf`

Here is what I am trying to do:

- mydomain.com --> use ssl certificate and load a index.html
- sub.mydomain.com --> use ssl certificate and load a index.html in a different folder
- redirect http requests to https

So, what are the differences between the three config files? Which one is the "active" one (which one is "applied")? I created the ssl.conf by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7#step-3-%E2%80%94-configure-tlsssl-on-web-server-(nginx)) tutorial, but I still don't get the "idea behind it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the `nginx` configuration file. Any other files or directories used to construct the final configuration must be explicitly referenced from within that file, either directly or indirectly using the `include` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.

There are a number of conventions out there, but you can choose to put everything into a single file, or split out servers and common configuration into separate files.